# Is there a way to use a variable as a parameter in rgba() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, graphics, rgba

This is my Javascript code.

```
var radius = random(20,200);
    var randRed = random(210,255);
    var randAlpha = random(0.25,0.4);
    var Color = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)';
    this.x = random(100, 700);
    this.y = random(100, 500);
    this.width = radius;
    this.height = radius;
    this.color = Color;
    this.velocityX = random(-5, +5);
    this.velocityY= random(-5, +5);
```

For context, this is used in a constructor in a class `Bubble` to create randomized circular bubbles. I found a way to randomize radius and position, but is there any way to use `randRed` and `randAlpha` as the red and alpha values for the `rgba()` in the `Color` variable?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
var Color = 'rgba(randRed,255,255,randAlpha);
```

Is this possible?
Here is the rest of the code:

```js
class Bubble {

  constructor() {
    var allInstances = [];

    var radius = random(20, 200);
    var randRed = random(210, 255);
    var randAlpha = random(0.25, 0.4);
    var Color = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)';
    this.x = random(100, 700);
    this.y = random(100, 500);
    this.width = radius;
    this.height = radius;
    this.color = Color;
    this.velocityX = random(-5, +5);
    this.velocityY = random(-5, +5);

    this.display = function() {
      stroke(255);
      fill(this.color);
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    this.move = function() {
      this.x = this.x + this.velocityX;
      this.y = this.y + this.velocityY;
    }

  }
}

var bubbles = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  bubble1 = new Bubble();
  bubble2 = new Bubble();
  bubble3 = new Bubble();
  bubble4 = new Bubble();
  bubble5 = new Bubble();
  bubble6 = new Bubble();
}


function draw() {
  background(56, 226, 232);
  bubble1.move();
  bubble2.move();
  bubble3.move();
  bubble4.move();
  bubble5.move();
  bubble6.move();

  bubble1.display();
  bubble2.display();
  bubble3.display();
  bubble4.display();
  bubble5.display();
  bubble6.display();
}

setInterval(function() {
  setup();
  draw();
}, 2900);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps search for “interpolate variable in string” or “concat strings”? (The variable itself does not exist outside of JS; however, it’s quite possible to ‘freeze’ the value of a JS variable in a string used as a CSS value.)

Comment: yes. It's called using template strings i.e. `\`rgba(${randRed},255,255,randAlpha);\``

Answer (score 0):

Try template literals:

```
let randRed = parseInt(random(210, 255));
let randAlpha = random(0.25, 0.40).toFixed(2);
let color = `rgba(${randRed}, 255, 255, ${randAlpha})`;
```

praseInt(x) parses x and returns an integer. eg:

```
let num = '210.23';
let res = parseInt(num); // res will be equal to 210
```

y.toFixed(x) rounds the number y to x decimal places. eg:

```
let num = 0.288682;
let res = num.toFixed(2); // res will be equal to 0.29
```

Note: You can call toFixed() to round the num to zero decimal places. ie, you can call toFixed() for randRed also.

Comment: I would advise against using "var" if it's not legacy code that's worked on, use ES2015 "let" or "const" instead. 
Also naming "Color" is strange (by requester himself), capitals are better used only if it signifies a class, at least by convention. This helps to avoid confusion by others (your future, more professional, self at least) who would expect it to be a class, not just string.

Comment: yes, True. I was following with Ishaan Masil's code. Thank you for noting. @okram . I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried using template literals as you said, but the bubbles just become opaque white again. I'm using editor.p5js.org, does that have something to do with it? Here is the link:
https://editor.p5js.org/darkknightishaan/sketches/mXgN5Z_72

Comment: ok.. logging the color the randRed have decimal places and randAlpha have way too many decimal places. Do parseInt for randRed and toFixed(2) for randAlpha. I've edited the answer. Please do look into it.

Comment: Also, No, the issue is not with the editor.p5js.org. It was with the values which were stored in randRed and randAlpha.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the code works now. There's one more thing though. Is there a way to make the same code generate bubbles endlessly using the `setInterval()` function without resetting the canvas as it does now?

Comment: @IshaanMasil ok. that's out of this question. eventhen, I don'think setInterval() is a problem here. You have to rework the `setup()` and `draw()`. Since. what currently being executed is that after 2.9 seconds new canvas is created in `setup()`. I hope this gives you some idea. Please check as answer and upvote if you found the answer to the question. Thank you.